# Search a named array in javascript

Tags: javascript

This might be a duplicate but I could not help but post this, I have an array with this format

```
answerCollection= {
0:
{selected : a,
 status :  false   
 },
1:
{selected : a,
 status :  false   
 }
}
```

I want to do an index check on the this aray like this

```
if(answerCollection.indexOf(indexNo) == -1){
 sel = "a";
 }
```

but it keeps failing i.e. I keep getting a return value of -1, irrespectively of if the index exist in the array or not.

How do I do this kind of search?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: Seems like `answerCollection` is a plain object instead of array. Also, the argument for `indexOf` is the value and not the key.

Comment: What happens if you do `if (!answerCollection[indexNo]) { ... }`?

Comment: I declared it like dis var answerCollection = [];

Comment: @Lloyd I passed it to a var to check, I keep getting -1 on it

Comment: @kolexinfos: …and then you did overwrite it, using an object literal.

Comment: What is `indexNo`? The `{selected: a, status: false}` object that is present in `answerCollection`?

Comment: @Bergi yes it is present in the array

Comment: @kolexinfos: Is it an object that only looks like that, or is `indexNo === answerCollection[0]`?

Comment: it was declared as array,dat was just to give a picture/format I had values like you do to an array answerCollection[indexNo] = {selected : selectedOption};, i dont understand why someone would call it an object

Comment: best practice is use the "in" operator. Check out my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(answerCollection[indexNo] == null){
 sel = "a";
}
```

for example look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CNwBE/2/).

Comment: @Lloyd `null` coerces to `undefined`. `undefined` can be shadowed, `null` can't. `null` is shorter to type and in file size.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes I forgot about that :)

Comment: Oh no problem. Since we're nitpicking, I'd go with `if (!answerCollection[indexNo])` `=]`

Comment: :) I prefer my null, since I defined the collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(indexNo in answerCollection){
 sel = "a";
 }
```

Best practice to [detect properties](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=J5RCV8yM7sEC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=Detecting%20Properties%20maintainable%20javascript&source=bl&ots=TD_vBBhYGn&sig=u1MpQgP58blzIKZr7WxQ5cLRZ1U&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=J_itUaSONo6RiQe8yYH4Bg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Detecting%20Properties%20maintainable%20javascript&f=false) in an object.
In your case, maybe you need to convert to string

```
if(indexNo.toString() in answerCollection){
     sel = "a";
     }
```

Comment: Probably right, but explain what it does (or link to docs) to avoid confusion!